# watchguard port forwarding via SNAT

Tags: port-forwarding, remote-desktop-services, watchguard

I have a problem with port forwarding on Watchguard.
What I want? I need to access from Internet via public IP on different port (lets say 9999) to a Remote Desktop on a PC which is on local network (win 10).

What I did?

- I created a SNAT policy, where I chose External (with certain IP address - my gateway-watchguard public IP),
- Internal IP Address - I set as a my WIN 10 on local network (10.10.0.1)
- I ticked internal port as 3389 (RDP)

then,

- I created a custom firewall policy with protocol TCP 9999
  and I used it where I set FROM (as my public IP where my whole traffic goes in and out), and TO I set as SNAT(public IP->10.10.0.1:3389)

Now, as I belive, whole traffic which comes outside my local network on port 9999 should be forwarded to 10.10.0.1 on port 3389?

But it's not working. I tried to connect via Windows RDP -> publicIP:9999 and nothing.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: If you only want to change the forwarded ports, you need port forwarding, not SNAT. Does it matter from which public IP you connect? If not, set port forwarding 9999->10.10.0.1:3389. You are confusing some terms, I suppose. **S**NAT changes the **source**, not the destination.

Comment: Hey, I have few public IP's so I want to use that watchguard's, that's why I set which public IP, but probably that should work also as 'any external'. 

And I belive, on watchguard there is no other way to set FROM which port TO which port (except using SNAT).

Comment: Oh my, I just checked the Watchguard docs, they use SNAT as _static_ NAT, not _source_ NAT. OK, so you're on the right track. To debug this, I'd set the external IP to _any_, then trace the packets on your Win10 machine, look if anything at all reaches port 3389.

Comment: OK, it's working now. Actually it was working from the beginning but my WiFi provider blocked port 9999 so that's why the packet's wasn't going out.

Comment: Alright. Glad you got it working. You should answer your own question, then.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve port forwarding on Watchguard you need to:

- create a SNAT (static NAT) policy with proper External source,
- set Internal IP Address as a your wanted PC (local IP) and tick a 
  different internal port (3389 in case of RDP).
- create custom firewall with any **selected** port and set FROM (as wanted External source) and IN as that SNAT.

That means, that whole traffic which comes from external source on **selected** port will be redirected into your PC in local network on port 3389 (RDP).

Be sure that you are not blocking those ports.

Comment: But in my case i am getting redirect on home page of my firewall. Do you any idea about it ?